# NewAer send image over BLE

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on app where we need to share images over ble, app is for both android and iOS so we are going for [NewAer](https://newaer.com/). We are able to Advertise, scan, send strings but not able to send images as [NewAer say here](http://newaer.com/apps/share/) we can send files. But I am not able to find any document regarding this nor any tutorial **/** code over NewAer web site.

Below is my working code to send strings (**works as expected**):-

```
- (IBAction)sendStringAsData {

NAMessage *message = [NAMessage new];

message.data = [@"Message" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[NAPlatform sharedNAPlatform] sendMessage:message to:deviceFound.deviceId];

}
```

And below is what I am trying to send image (**not working**) :-

```
- (IBAction)sendImageAsData {

NAMessage *message = [NAMessage new];

message.data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleDataImage"]);

[[NAPlatform sharedNAPlatform] sendMessage:message to:deviceFound.deviceId];

}
```

I have also make time out changes in NAMessage.h, but no luck.

```
NAMESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 9999
```

I am not sure that NewAer is able to send files over BLE or not, Please help me else if any one have better option to share files over BLE with cross plat-form (iOS, Android) please share with me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: BLE can only send 20 bytes at a time, so you need to know whether their SDK can split the data into multiple transmissions and reassemble it on the other side. Perhaps ask them?  From the link in your question it looks like files are uploaded to Google drive and then a link is shared

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, we are using NewAer to share the URI of the file on the cloud, not the P2P of the transfer.  That being said, we can send 15K between iOS devices, or iOS and the Raspberry Pi 3.  As Android gains further support for BLE, we expect to ad that higher file size as well, but at this time it is limited to 500 bytes between Android and iOS.